# Android, open camera within application

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs, camera, fragment

I am very inexperienced working with the camera API, but I need it for a mock-up I am putting together.  I am working on an app that will have a barcode scanner, but for the first rendition of the project I don't actually need any sort of functionality from it.  All that I need is to open the camera view so that it is contained within one of the fragment tabs inside of a Tabbed Activity.  I don't need to do any scanning or take any pictures, just have the rear camera display inside the fragment.  Is there a simple way to implement this?  I have already looked over the Developer docs for camera intents and I can't make much sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

From what you say, I understand you need to build a custom camera layout. Please check Android documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

Comment: he said I have already looked over the `Developer docs` for camera intents and I can't make much sense of it.